# get rid of annotation in pdf file using imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

I translate pdf to jpg using imagick;

but it return area with black color because of annotations existing in pdf file, annotaions apear when I hover pictures in pdf file

image file:

[image]

origine pdf exemple:

[image]

my code :

```
$img = new Imagick('./pige.pdf[1]');
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('white');

$img = $img->flattenImages();

$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->writeImage('image.jpg');
```

Comment: Your original file is PNG. We need the actual PDF. Please zip the PDF and post the zip file.

Comment: @fmw42 this the [pdf file ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qmaKBA5vd-2_I4WlpZs8oInKGONNOBRb/view?usp=sharing ) in drive

Comment: When I render that pdf in Imagemagick command line, I get two black squares in the bottom part of the image. But I cannot seem to get rid of them. Imagemagick use Ghostscript to process PDF files. So the issue is likely with GS.

Comment: I think it's because of annotation on pdf file, because when you hover these area on pdf with annotations activated, you will see this yellow squares, like on the picture above

Comment: There is something in your PDF that GS cannot handle, is my thought.

Answer (score 0):

so I the solution is to change the gs installed by default with imagick :

This appears to be a bug in the ghostscript version that is installed with ImageMagick by default. Ghostscript is the program that actually does the conversion from pdf to a rendered bitmap.

I tried the latest version of Ghostscript that I downloaded from: https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Converting your PDF with the command line:

```
gs-9540-linux-x86_64 -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' '-sOutputFile=/var/app/bugs/bug389/gs_output.png' '-f/var/app/bugs/bug389/pige.pdf'
```

and it appears to work okay.

I think if you:

- find where ghost script is on your machine by running which gs
- then just replace that file (after backing the original one up
  somewhere) with the one downloaded from
  https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html that may make your
  problem go away.